# how to get rid of \n?

Tags: python, string, list

`'Account\n688997'` is one string of many strings in my list and this happens more than once. I've tried `replace(r'\n',',')`, I've tried doing a for loop with `.strip()` and I can get it to print without it (naturally) but I can't get it to print out in the list without the `\n`. What I would like is `['Account','688997']` but what I always get is `['Account\n688997']`.

Comment: Could you give an example on how you create such a string? And how do you print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string split function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split lists based on the newline:

```
>>> s = 'Account\n688997'
>>> s.split()
['Account', '688997']
>>> # You can also make the split more explicit by passing the `\n` to the `str.split` function
>>> s.split('\n')
['Account', '688997']
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split()` is suitable for your problem ,

```
print('Account\n688997'.split())
```

output:

```
['Account', '688997']
```